# Trouble losing weight, need help creating a diet and workout plan

Tags: weight-loss, diet, workout-routines

I am a 20 year old male and have been at my current height and weight, 5'8" and 190 lbs, since I was 16. I have tried dieting and exercising but see no results. This past summer I spent 3 months doing heavy weight training and cutting my calorie intake. While I increased my strength greatly I did not lose any weight or inches on my waist.

One of the hardest parts of dieting is that I need to eat, or else I get crippling migraines. Another issue is that being in college makes me at the mercy of the dining hall in terms of food options.

Being in College also gives me very limited time that I can spend working out. Based on my current work and class schedules I can get into the gym maybe every other day for an hour. Otherwise my exercise would need to be things I can work into by daily schedule.

**What would be the best diet and exercise plan for my situation, or what minor adjustments could I make to help me lose weight, especially mid section body fat?**

Comment: Are you tracking your calories and exercise? If not do that. Are your workouts getting objectively harder (more reps, more weight, more time)? If not they should.

Comment: This needs to be a lot more specific. Try [adding some information](http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/a/517/1771) on what you've been doing in your workouts and what you've been eating.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot spot reduce.  Losing weight in a specific area is not possible.  As Lego Stormtroopr indicates, start by tracking your calories, carbohydrate, protein, and fats.  Then, make a small adjustment in the amount of each nutrient you are consuming. Say, cut out 500 calories for the **week**. Do try to lose more than 1 to 2 pounds per week.  Anything more and you may be catabolizing muscle tissue.